# Django Many To Many field with filter

Tags: django, filter, many-to-many, admin

I am trying to add a filter to my ManyToMany field.

I have a model User and a model Notification. Notification is connected with User by a ManyToMany field. I want to be able to send a Notification to all users that are for example located in Bulgaria or filter them based on another property in the user model which is not predefined(i.e. The person who creates the Notification does not know pre-creation the filter field).

I tried using `raw_id_fields` for User in Notification admin page. I can then chose and filter Users I want to add based on filters in the Model but I can only choose one user at a time and if I have to add, for example 10k users this can be quite inconvenient.
[image]
 I want to be able to either use `raw_id_field` and select multiple instances at once, or add some field filtration to `filter_horizontal` or I don't know.

Comment: Are you trying to send a notification to multiple users, based on their region or any other filtering criteria? Sorry your question is not clear.

Comment: Yes that is what I was trying to do, but I just found a sort of work around fix for this.

Comment: I added a custom action to User Model page - I create an empty notification with all of the selected users attached to the many2many relation and after that when I go to the Notifications Model page I just fill in the other properties of the notification and save it. I have a separate logic that on save I need to send a message through a socket to all users that are in the many2many relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what your looking for is this:

```
list_filter = ['user__located']
```

That will let you filter Notifications by the `located` attribute on Users.

Comment: Cool! I was just reading about the list_filter option. Cheers! :)